# Building NDK Applications (ipcamera)

Tags: android

1. I Downloaded Svn Code IPcamera which an Android application for Live Streaming Media From Android camera to Browser from the link [ipcamera-for-android/source/checkout](http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/source/checkout).
2. Then I downloaded related library talk from `svn co http://libjingle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/talk talk -r103`
3. Linux Terminal I changed my path up-to  the source path `/Downloads/ipcamera/trunk/droidipcam`.

I build using ndk-build command :

```
Documents/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build
```

I got following Errors :

```
Compile++ thumb  : ipcamera <= ipcamera.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : ipcamera <= mediacheck.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : ipcamera <= mediapak.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : ipcamera <= mediabuffer.cpp
In file included from jni/mediabuffer.cpp:3:
jni/mediabuffer.h:6:31: error: talk/base/sigslot.h: No such file or directory
jni/mediabuffer.h:7:39: error: talk/base/criticalsection.h: No such file or directory
In file included from jni/mediabuffer.cpp:3:
jni/mediabuffer.h:36: error: 'sigslot' has not been declared
jni/mediabuffer.h:36: error: expected '{' before 'has_slots'
jni/mediabuffer.h:36: error: expected initializer before '<' token
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/ipcamera/mediabuffer.o] Error 1
```

4)  After this I placed the Downloded talk library in the Path     `/Downloads/ipcamera/trunk/droidipcam`.

Still I got following error:

```
Invalid attribute name: 
      package
make: *** No rule to make target `jni/talk/base/common.cc', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/teaonly/talk/base/common.o'.  Stop.
shilpa@shilpa-Vostro-260s:~/Downloads/ipcamera/trunk/droidipcam$ /home/teaonly/opt/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build
bash: /home/teaonly/opt/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need download the rest of resources from http://libjingle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/talk

For example you need talk/base/sigslot.h and other class for a complete compilation.

Comment: Provided like not found ,I have also same issue can u plz provide me source code

Answer (score 0):

Put the talk folder inside the JNI folder.
Then execute: Documents/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build