# Make Errors - NDK Build (ipcamera)

Tags: android, makefile, ip-camera

I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002471/building-ndk-applications-ipcamera) and get

*** No rule to make target '/jni/talk/base/time.cc', needed by `/obj/local/armeabi/objs/teaonly/talk/base/time.o'.  Stop. ***

I'm on 64bit Win7. Is there a missing make file with rev 207 of the libjingle?

Comment: Make sure about your paths and you have added all the resources which is needed.

Comment: I svn checkedout http://libjingle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ . Is it wrong to assume that this would have the files in the correct spot? I navigate my command prompt to the folder above the checked out folder and run the ndk-build. It creates a couple object before getting to time.o .

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to compile and run. The issue was that there were several resources missing from the most recent rev. And then you have to edit a couple spots to get it to use the front camera.

The flowplayer on the website hosted by the device wouldn't play the stream. VLC will play it.

There's a 11 second delay for about 10 minutes and then a 3 second delay. Wont work for what I want to do. Thanks  juned for the hint.

Comment: can you make this line *The issue was that there were several resources missing from the most recent rev* more clear? I am facing the same issue in same configuration. I have used the files from: `http://libjingle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`

Comment: I had to use revision 128 as time.cc is removed on revision 129.  After doing this I was able to build